# Exchanging the values of char pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I was trying something ... and I am unable to understand the result

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

char *remove_vowels_string(char *p);

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char str[77],*getString;
    gets(str);
    getString=remove_vowels_string(str);
    puts("\n");
    puts(getString);
    getch();
}

char *remove_vowels_string(char *p)
{
    char *q;
    q=p;
    while(*p)
    {
        if(*p=='a' || *p=='e' || *p=='i' || *p=='o' || *p=='u')
        {
            for(int i=0;*(p+i)!='\o';i++)
            // printf(" as %d",i);
            {
                 *q=*(p+i);
                 *(p+i)=*(p+i+1);
                if(*(p+i+1)=='\o')
                    break;

                    *(p+i+1)=*q;
            }

            printf("\n%c\n",*p);
            *(p+i+1)='\o';
        }
        p++;
    }
    puts(p);
    return p;
}
```

I wanted to shift each value forward, and replace the vowel char by a null pointer. But the program is not working. Please tell where I have gone wrong and why I have gone wrong.

Comment: NUL-terminator is `\0`, not `\o`

Comment: Oh the horror! What is that coding style / indentation?

Comment: @LordZsolt , Rolled Back your edit. Why in the world did you change `\n` into `n` and `\o` into `o`???

Comment: @CoolGuy Sorry, just copy pasted the code into a prettifier, didn't notice \s were removed. Should be ok now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\o` is not the same as `\0`. `\o` will be treated as `o`. [Reference](http://ideone.com/RSOJsb)

```
 for(int i=0;*(p+i)!='\o';i++)
```

should be

```
 for(int i=0;*(p+i)!='\0';i++)
                       ^
                     This is the null character
```

Similarly,

```
if(*(p+i+1)=='\o')
```

should be

```
if(*(p+i+1)=='\0')
```

and

```
*(p+i+1)='\o';
```

should be

```
*(p+i+1)='\0';
```

Also note that you should be using

```
int main()
{
  // your code
  return 0;
}
```

instead of `void main()`

Answer (score 1):

Catch! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cctype.h>


char * remove_vowels( char *s ) 
{
    const char *vowels = "aeiou";

    char *q = s; 

    while ( *q && !strchr( vowels, tolower( *q ) ) ) ++q; 

    char *p = q; 

    while ( *q ) 
    { 
        if ( !*++q || !strchr( vowels, tolower( *q ) ) ) *p++ = *q; 
    } 

    return s; 
 } 

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    puts( s );
    puts( remove_vowels( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz
```

As you made a typo and wrote `'\o'` instead of `'\0'`  I decided to exclude entirely this escape character from the function.:)